# DotnetOpenAuth tutorial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, dotnetopenauth

Is there any tutorial available on how to use DotNetOpenAuth library? How to use the database which comes with the ASP.NET Authentication and extend it to use OpenAuth library?

Thanks

Comment: What did your search on the Internet get you?

Comment: I could not find any articles talking about how I could integrate the DB used in Forms Auth into OpenAuth library